# How to set Label's ID and runat in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In index.aspx

```
<asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" style="display:none" runat="server" Text="title"></asp:Label>
```

How to index.cshtml inside write the same function statement? If it's a button or a hyperlink, What should I write here? Anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no runat property in MVC. Just write pure html.

Comment: Use HtmlHelper like this `@Html.Label()`

Comment: I try
@Html.Label("title", new {id= "TitleLabel"})
However, Visual Studio prompts the error "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter htmlAttributes of 'lHtmIHelper, Label(string, string, object)'"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.label?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2